# MS Speech Platform 11 Helena Spanish voice does not play interrogative intonation for TTS

Tags: text-to-speech

I am working on VB.NET application that uses the MS Speech Platform 11 SDK.  I have noticed a problem with the MS Helena Spanish voice when playing Spanish text as audio. If the text contains a question, that is, text enclosed with an upside-down and a normal question mark, the audio is not spoken with the intonation of a question.  When I use the MS Helen English voice, the text is spoken using the intonation of a question as you would want.  I have tried getting around this by adjusting different attributes such as pitch for the Spanish but have not had any success so far.  I will continue to investigate.

Please let me know if you have any questions or need further information.

Thanks,
Gil

Comment: So, what have you tried?  And, more to the point, what do you want the SO community to do?